# Custom tilte gone from actionbar when using screensize attribute

Tags: android

When rotate screen  Custom tilte gone from actionbar when using screensize attribute ,i don't want to call onCreate() again.

Comment: What's a tilte? (Also, whether you want to call onCreate or not, if you just rotated the screen, it probably *did* get called...)

Comment: custom title like spinner in action bar ,and i won't call onCreate() again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem, thank you. I just used:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
    R.layout.spinner_layout, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(spinner);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTitle()` method of the `ActionBar` to set the title again. However, when orientation changes, your `onCreate()` will be called again.

Comment: i put this line in my manifest android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden",so onCreate() won't be called